# JPQL in clause with enum

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have application based on spring boot 1.2.3. One of the model is very specific: contains list of enums. When I try to call by spring jpa query part of sql disappear [**c.categories IN (:category)** is replaced with **(. in (?))**]. I guess it can be some issue in library or maybe I made something wrong.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Log catch SQL:

```
select count(myobject0_.id) as col_0_0_ from myobject myobject0_ cross join myobject0_categories categories1_ where myobject0_.id=categories1_.myobject_id and (. in (?))
```

Error:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 07001
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
```

Original JPQL from interface:

```
@Query("from Myobject c where and c.categories IN (:category)")
Page<Myobject> findAll(@Param("category") Set<Category> categories, Pageable pageable);
```

Target model contains:

```
@Column(name = "category")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "myobject_categories", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "myobject_id"))
    private Set<Category> categories;
```

Enum model:

```
public enum Category {
CATEGORY(1), CATEGORY2(2);

private final Integer id;

Category(Integer id) { this.id=id; }

public Integer getId() { return id; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would be valid JPQL, available for use in any compliant JPA 2 provider

```
SELECT c FROM Myobject c WHERE :category MEMBER OF c.categories
```

Comment: This is correct, but it doesn't work when I send list of params.

Comment: so raise a bug with your JPA provider

Comment: Ok. Probably this solution is the best. Also your JPQL statement is correct, so I accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution is to inverse IN clause and then jpql will create subquery. Quite ugly, but it works.

```
@Query("from Myobject c where :category in elements(c.categories)")
Page<Myobject> findAll(@Param("category") Set<Category> categories, Pageable pageable);
```

Logged SQL:

```
select count(myobject0_.id) as col_0_0_ from myobject myobject0_ where (myobject0_.updated is not null) and (? in (select categories1_.category from comic_categories categories1_ where myobject0_.id=categories1_.comic_id))
```

Comment: There is no such keyword "elements" in JPQL, and JPQL starts with "SELECT {alias}"